# How to map a list of key/value pairs from YAML into a Spring Configuration Properties Map?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have the following YAML properties:

```yaml
application:
  security:
    api:
      - key: "main-application"
        secret: "127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f71"
      - key: "admin"
        secret: "127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f72"
```

My goal is to have the api keys mapped into a `Map<String, String>` where the `Map#entry()`s would look like this:

```java
Map.entry("main-application", "127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f71");
Map.entry("admin", "127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f72");
```

At the moment I'm having a really hard time to get these values mapped automatically through `@ConfigurationProperties`. I tried the following:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.security")
public record ApiKeys(Map<String, String> api) { }
```

But the result is a Map with 4 entries instead of the expected 2:

```
api={0.key=main-application,
     0.secret=127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f71,
     1.key=admin,
     1.secret=127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f72}
```

Does anybody know how the get the properties mapped properly into a single map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
application:
  security:
    api:
      main-application: 127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f71
      admin: 127ab3a8-b496-42ae-8b7c-2433fa010f72
```

Just what you need?

Comment: Yes @DingHao, that would be a solution. But unfortunately it is required to keep the YAML structure (key and secret) as described. So what I need is a way to convert the properties from a List with named key/value pairs into a Map.

Comment: If you insist on keeping the configuration structure,you can define helper method as below
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.security")
    public record ApiKeys(List<Map<String, String>> api) {
        public Map<String, String> getApi() {
            return api.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a->a.get("key"),a->a.get("secret")));
        }
    }

Comment: Well, I think you're right. It seems the best way is to use a helper method. Although I'll ended up with a dedicated record collecting the api values for a little more self explaining style, eventually it's the same. Many thanks.